# "Live" code and rapid prototyping with C++ and LLVM JIT?

Tags: c++, compilation, real-time, llvm, jit

You might have already seen [Bret Victor's "live" JS IDE](http://vimeo.com/36579366), or some of the [alternative implementations](http://www.kickstarter.com/projects/ibdknox/light-table) it inspired, extending to other languages, but still keeping it to VM based ones.

Yesterday however, I stumbled upon [the same concept, applied in good old C++](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=imkVkRg-geI), thanks to LLVM. Still a very early and immature implementation, but with plenty of potential.

I was really curious of the implementation however the author has and might not release it to the open.

So my question is if anyone is aware of a resource on how to implement similar functionality, I mean the almost instantaneous compilation and the two connection, giving realtime feedback of the code, allowing the visual part to change or even generate and preview additional code?

Comment: It is not very "real time" in that demo - a pretty typical compilation delay, actually. As for that colour picker example, apparently, it is done via some kind of trivial instrumentation (very easy to do with LLVM). E.g., detecting all the `Colour(...)` constructors and lifting their arguments into global variables.

Comment: As you say yourself it's done with LLVM. You should look at LLVM as that's the "resource on how to implement similar functionality". The project contains several subprojects. Including a very advanced C/C++/ObjC preprocessor (Apple uses it to implement all XCode advanced features), actual compilers from several languages to the LLVM intermediate representation code (aka LLVM IR which is an assembler like language but with SSA), optimizers that work on LLVM IR, code generators that translate LLVM IR to actual binary and also an interpreter (with JIT capability) of LLVM IR.

Comment: @AnalogFile - LLVM is the API, I am asking about resources on how to do that with the API. I checked some of the examples they provide, but those are fairly basic. I was hoping there is something to help me avoid digging into the documentation to figure things the tedious way.

Comment: Well, that sort of thing is currently cutting edge kind of stuff. I do not think there will be tutorials on how to do that for at least a decade. I can _picture_ how it works in my head, but it's not easy at all, involves a hell of a lot of code and knowledge of the internals of a very advanced compiler. Until internals of an advanced compiler are _common knowledge_ this is not meat for a tutorial or generic resource.

Comment: It's a bit like asking how to write an optimized scheduler for an operating system. You started having some info about those things only in the late 80s and in the 90s (especially in the 90s when Linux, BSD and open source OSs became common). Still need to know a lot of internals to actually do one.

Answer (score 2):

The clang-based C/C++ interpreter called "Cling" may be relevant piece of code. See how it can be used to build GUI in real time: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrjV1ZgYbbA

Answer (score 0):

Linux: If anyone wants a naive way to test a quick C/C++ code in almost real time, you can use this piece of code I assembled:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Requires: inotify-tools
################################
# Adjust values:
terminal="xterm"
editor="vim"
compiler="clang++"
################################
if [[ $1 == "" ]]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 example.cpp";
    exit
fi
file_to_edit=$1
file_output=${file_to_edit%%.*}
(while(true); do 
    change=$(inotifywait -q -e close_write,moved_to,create .);
    change=${change#./ * }
    if [ "$change" = "$file_to_edit" ]; then
        ($compiler $file_to_edit -o $file_output);
    fi
done) & > /dev/null
$terminal -e "watch -n 1 ./$file_output" &
$editor $file_to_edit;
pkill -P $$
```

NOTE: It requires "inotify-tools" package.

How does it works?

1) It will open a terminal (default: xterm) in which every second will be executing the binary file using the 'watch' command (if no file exists it will just display a 'not found error')

2) If your C/C++ code changes, it will compile it (default compiler: clang++, but you can use gcc, etc). You can modify the compile command if you want at: `$compiler $file_to_edit -o $file_output`

3) It will open the file with your selected editor (defaults to vim).

4) On exit will close the terminal and the monitoring process.